# Confusion Regarding Interaction Energy Of A System With A Dipole

Tags: electrostatics, potential

In a system with a dipole of dipole moment $\overrightarrow{P_1}$ and a positive charge $q$ at a distance $r$, my teacher found the electric potential at the point of positive charge due to the dipole and then found the interaction energy of the system using $$U=qV$$
My question is why don't we consider the potential energy between the charges of the dipole? Wouldn't that be $U=-\frac{kq^2}{d}$ and hence decrease the value of the interaction energy of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dipole, by definition, has a fixed separation between its positive and negative part - throughout all of the dynamics, the extra $-kq^2/d$ is an irrelevant constant that does not alter any  of the physics. The electric potential $U$ is only defined up to a constant - its numerical value at a point is irrelevant, all that matters is how it changes in space.

Comment: Oh so its like adding a constant c to the value of U every time we calculate it and instead of doing that we can just neglect it since change in U is more important than value of U and when calculating change of U it will always get cancelled. Thanks a lot!!!